# Visual C# questionon CheckedListBox control (VS2008)

Tags: c#

I would like to force a CheckedListBox to have one or more of its boxes checked from within form load so the user sees some defaults checked when the app first loads.... I have tried the SetSelected method...this highlights the text of the selected  box but doesn't show a tick. 
Any help gratefully recieved
THanks
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`SetItemChecked` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SetItemChecked()` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked.aspx

Answer (score 0):

checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);